# What is this function definition style the author is using here?

Tags: r

learning R with, The Art of R Programming.
Until about 1/2 through he has simply defined a new function like this:

```
fnc=function(a,b){
return(a) }
```

But now is doing stuff like this:

```
> g
function() {
t <- function(x) return(x^2)
return(t)
}

> g()
function(x) return(x^2)
```

Is this the same as saying:

```
g=function(x) return(x^2)
```

What is the g in the first block?
Running the exact code he has does not work for me, it just prints out what I had in g.

Thank you everyone.

Comment: i think you're missing a `<-`. i.e. `g <- function() { t <-…`. it could be a typo in the book

Comment: I thought so too, but he does the same thing to 2 places where it looks like he is defining a function but it is just like the above. A letter, new line, then function()

Comment: I think my wife has a copy of the book in her office, do you have the page #'s these appear on?

Answer (score 1):

If your code transposition from book to SO is accurate, the author is defining a function that returns a function:

```
g <- function() {
  t <- function(x) return(x^2)
  return(t)
}
```

We can see that if we execute it:

```
g()

## function(x) return(x^2)
## <environment: 0x7fd7c5aa7d10>
```

And, we can use the fact that it returns a function by passing in a parameter to what it returns either this way:

```
g()(10)
## 100
```

or this way:

```
squareIt <- g()
squareIt(10)
## 100
```